# Running mapreduce on portable devices

Tags: android, hadoop, mapreduce

I have heard of people who have successfully run mapreduce on a google nexus one. There is no more info on the performance of running a full clustered mapreduce on android.

I would really like to run mapreduce on my phone on a relatively small amount of data non clustered mode, is it really worth it to use the hadoop completely ? is there a stripped version available anywhere? any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire point of using a process like map reduce is to split up the workload across multiple computers simultaneously achieving concurrency not possible on current computers.  If you don't have any plans to federate multiple android devices then there is little need to use something like hadoop.

If you can load all of the data on the device (which is what you're saying you can do).  The closest thing to running an algorithm in parallel would be to use multiple threads and split your data set up.  You don't have to do map reduce style programming to get the benefits of parallel programming and it might be easier to develop your algorithm as just a producer/consumer model.  But, if you just gotta have it here is a way to do it.

I'd start with two BlockingQueues (in-queue and out-queue) and a thread to read your data from a file (i.e. Producer).  Create a thread pool to read from the in-queue and write to the out-queue.  Each thread will do a computation on one of the inputs (i.e. Consumer), and post it's results to out-queue so the Producer can receive the results.  Doing one pass through the in-queue and out-queue will do half of the map-reduce process.  This is commonly referred to as producer/consumer.  You can do a lot with just that style architecture.

If you want to do a full map-reduce repeat the process so your reduce step runs in parallel.  The Producer would collect all results from the map step by key, and feed those back out to the in-queue.  Each Consumer would now do the reduce step, and post their results back to the out-queue, where the producer would do the final sort and present the results to a the UI.

Therefore the full state transition for the Producer would be:

1. Parse the input file, and create work loads to drop onto the in-queue.
2. Read results from the out-queue until all map processes are done.
3. Combine the results by key.
4. Write all results with the same key to the in-queue as one unit of work.  Repeat for all unique keys received.
5. Read all results coming back on the out-queue.

The Consumer state transitions would be:

1. Read a unit of work from the in-queue.
2. Perform the map logic on that unit of work.
3. Write the result + key to the out-queue.
4. Read a unit of work from the in-queue.
5. Perform the reduce logic on that unit of work.
6. Write the result to the out-queue.

Viola map reduce style framework on android.